# dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 10; 2 is required

Tags: python, openerp-7, odoo, openerp-8, odoo-8

I only want the sucursal from res.users and I don't know how get it.

```
def _user_sucursal(self, cr, uid, ids, field, arg, context = None):
    suc = self.pool.get('res.users')
    ids = suc.search (cr, uid, [])
    res = suc.read(cr, uid, ids, ['id'],['sucursal_u'], context)
    res = [(r['id'], r['sucursal']) for r in res] 
    return res
```

Comment: The only sequence with a length of 10 in your code is `'sucursal_u'`.  It seems possible that the argument `['sucursal_u']` is supposed to be different.  Perhaps `[('sucursal_u', 'another_arg?')]`.  Your question can be improved by giving the full traceback of your error, and by explaining more about the context of your code (what type of object is `self.pool`, etc.).  Your snippet is hard decipher without more context.  Without revision I doubt you will get a good answer.

Comment: Absent any edits to clarify the question I'm voting to close.

Comment: im trying to save in a field the sucursal_id from the logged user on the system so i can list all orders only from the sucursal from that user, if i can save the sucursal_u in a field but i really dont know if the funtion can get only one answer, in this case the sucursal from the logged user. i hope i had explained this better